# Plotly : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&&'

Tags: plotly

I am unable to plot bar charts using plotly.express.
Getting below error -
*" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&&' "*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a bug in Plotly 5.8 which will be fixed in 5.8.1 https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3756

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error as the original poster.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(x=df_month['month'].astype(dtype=str), 
                    y=df_month['counts'],
                    marker_color='indianred', text="counts"))
fig.update_layout({"title": 'Tweets about Malioboro from Jan 2020 to Jan 2021',
               "xaxis": {"title":"Months"},
               "yaxis": {"title":"Total tweets"},
               "showlegend": False})

fig.show()
```

I'm trying to create a line chart in Databricks with Plotly (eventually will connect my Databricks notebook to Plotly Dash Enterprise.  I started by following this blog post (https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-plot-timeseries-data-in-python-and-plotly-1382d205cc2) I have everything as a direct copy of the code.

I am running Python 3.7 and have Plotly upgraded to the most recent version.